# What would be the most efficient way of using 'BREAK BY' in a nested for each in Progress 4GL?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

Assume there are four tables like GroupH, GroupL, Member, Incident. If I write a nested for each like below,

```
for each GroupH use-index grouph-id
    NO-LOCK,
    each GroupL use-index groupl-id
    where GroupL.grphid = GroupH.grphid
    NO-LOCK,
    each Member use-index member-id
    where Member.memberid = GroupL.memberid
    NO-LOCK,
    each Incident use-index incident-key
    where Incident.memberid = Member.memberid
    NO-LOCK
    BREAK BY
        Member.memberid
        Member.schemid
        Member.emplid:

    //do something. 

end.
```

What could be the facts that can make my query significantly inefficient in relation to the 'BREAK BY' fields?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest positive change you can make is get rid of all the USE-INDEX phrases as that restricts the db engine to 1 index and prohibits index bracketing.

Beyond that, if FOR EACHs are from least amount of data to greatest amount of data, then these are fine.

Answer (score 1):

The significant factors that make queries inefficient are bad coding like USE-INDEX that overrides the optimizer and poor alignment of WHERE clause criteria with available indexes.

The most important factor in building an efficient query is for the WHERE clause to specify equality matches involving fields that are the leading components of indexes.

All of your WHERE clauses use equality matches -- that is good.

Is "where GroupL.grphid = GroupL.grphid" a typo? Did you really mean:

```
where GroupL.grphid = GroupH.grphid
```

In this case your ideal situation would be for GroupL.grphid to be the first component in some index.  If that index happens to be "groupl-id" then the USE-INDEX did no harm.  But if the index is NOT group-id you have prevented the optimizer from using it.  (It is almost always better to allow the compiler to choose -- 999 times out of 100 programmers who think that they know better are wrong.)

Likewise for your other nested queries.  Having no knowledge of the actual db schema and indexes I can only guess but it seems likely that:

```
each Incident use-index incident-key
    where Incident.memberid = Member.memberid
```

is problematic.  I would guess that "incident-key" is probably not an index where "memberid" is the first field.  And you are forcing its use.  This is probably not a good thing.

BREAK-BY only comes into play as a tie-breaker to choose an index after almost all other rules have been exhausted.  It has no significant impact on query performance.

If there are no indexes that can be used to satisfy the WHERE clause as described and the performance of the query needs to be improved then the next course of action is to add an index that fits the need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer I'm afraid i do not have enough reputation to upvote. Actually I have been forced to mention use-index for queries in my current working place as it is a must according to company coding standards. It says by using use-index it shows the developer understanding of thier own query as well as it forces Pregress to use optimal index. So what we do is going for the best defined index according to the query we are trying to run. So i assume if there are no indexes matches to the fields in the where clause you are suggesting me to go without use-index.

Comment: IMHO your company's coding standard is counter-productive and wrong-headed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Tom said... do yourself a favor and download ProTop or at least read up on the _UserTableStat and _UserIndexStat virtual system tables (VSTs).

You can use them to see exactly how many records are being read for each table. It makes it pretty easy to see where the performance problems are.